# How define a best threshold based on confidence level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, threshold

I have a Data Frame, it has a threshold that check based on `confidence1` if "Is the same person" or not. When the confidence is lower the person is different and the opposite when is greater.

[image: Data Frame]

How I can define the best threshold based on confidence?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want to achieve.
Common metrics to optimize in classification are:

1. Precision
2. Recall
3. F1 score
4. AUC ROC
   For those metrics you need the ground trush (weather or not if it is actually the same person).

In the case you do not have the ground trush, you could make your threshod vary and select the one that gives you the share of "Is the same person" equal to what you would like to have.